# Angular 5: How we Pass data from nested component to parent component using routeroutlet?

Tags: angular

**Scenario**

What I'm trying to do is send data from login component -> app component.

Below is my login.component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  isUserAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showMe() {
    this.isUserAuthenticated = this.isUserAuthenticated == false ? true : false;
    console.log('Log comming from login.component.ts: ' + this.isUserAuthenticated);
    this.auth.login(this.isUserAuthenticated);
    this.valueChange.emit(this.isUserAuthenticated);
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public isUserAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  login(params: boolean): Observable<boolean> {
    this.isUserAuthenticated = params;
    console.log('Log comming from auth.service.ts: ' + this.isUserAuthenticated);
    return new Observable<boolean>(observer => observer.next(this.isUserAuthenticated));
  }

}
```

app.component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isUserAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {;
    console.log('Log comming from app.component.ts: ' + this.auth.isUserAuthenticated);
    this.isUserAuthenticated = this.auth.isUserAuthenticated;
  }

  showMe(value) {
    console.log('Receiving data from login.component.ts: ' + value);
    this.isUserAuthenticated = value;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <app-nav-menu *ngIf="isUserAuthenticated"></app-nav-menu>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
      <router-outlet (valueChange)="showMe($event)"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

The problem which I'm facing is my @output emitter function `this.valueChange.emit(this.isUserAuthenticated);` is not working, and not hitting this `showMe(value)` function which is in login.component.ts. I don't know what I'am doing wrong in my code. Please have a look and help me. Thanks

I'm using Angular v5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Use a service and inject it in both components.

Components on the other side of a router outlet cannot communicate via an output because they are not in parent-child relationship *in the template*. You only park a place in the template where the router will dynamically instantiate the component, so the output is useless since there's no way to access it from the template.

With a service, it will be a singleton meaning both components will have access to the same instance after it is injected into them. You can use this to pass data, create events, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> *What I'm trying to do is send data from login component -> app component.*

Well you are complicating your task on your own demand. Use shared service to hold identity of user (and related methods like `isAuthenticated` and stuff).

You can then inject it in your `login` component and save user identity. Later on you can inject that service to any other component and get that data back.
Thats what `@Injectable`s are for